Web scraping in R using selector gadget
I am trying to web scrape the following site: https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/META/analysis
I faced few problems:
I used the selector gadget to highlight the tables. But it doesn't work as it should be. Then I typed "table" and then it highlighted 9 tables.
When I did
html <- read_html("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/META/analysis")
html %>% html_elements("table") %>% html_table()

It only gives 6 tables. How to get all these 9 tables?
Edited:
When I saved the HTML file and read it into R gave me 9 tables.
xml2:::read_html("test.html") %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()

Is there any reason why html doesn't have that information?
Edit2:
I tried the following code
html <- read_html_live("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/META/analysis")
html %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()

It worked.
Is it possible to get the URLs in Tables 7 and 8?

The page you have provided has only 6 tables in the source code. Go to that page and open source code with Ctrl+U.
The other 3 tables probably are generated with JavaScript. Probably you have saved with Ctrl+S.

I had a look at the source code. Yes it has 6 tables. When I select the "inspect" option, it has information about the remaining three tables too. I tried using read_html_live(), but it didn't work
